# Wordpress: Change position of post header

Tags: wordpress, image, title, wordpress-featured-image

I use the wordpress theme "Sahifa" where the default position of the post title is BELOW the featured image. I want to move i ABOVE the featured image.

Who can identify the piece of code that needs to be moved?

THANKS !!!

PLease find below my single.php

```
<?php if ( ! have_posts() ) : ?>
<div class="content">
    <?php get_template_part( 'framework/parts/not-found' ); ?>
</div>
<?php endif; ?>

<?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

<?php tie_setPostViews() ?>

<?php
    $get_meta = get_post_custom($post->ID);

    tie_update_reviews_info();

    if( !empty( $get_meta["tie_sidebar_pos"][0] ) && $get_meta["tie_sidebar_pos"][0] == 'full' ) $content_width = 955;

    $do_not_duplicate = array();

?>

<?php if( !empty( $get_meta["tie_post_head_cover"][0] ) ) : ?>
<div class="post-cover-head">
    <?php get_template_part( 'framework/parts/post-head' ); ?>
</div>
<?php endif; ?>

<div class="content<?php if( !empty( $get_meta["tie_post_head_cover"][0] ) ) echo ' post-cover';?>">

    <?php if(  empty( $get_meta["tie_post_head_cover"][0] ) ||
            ( !empty( $get_meta["tie_post_head_cover"][0] ) && ( !empty( $get_meta['tie_post_head'][0] ) && $get_meta['tie_post_head'][0] != 'thumb' ) ) ) : ?>

    <?php tie_breadcrumbs() ?>

    <?php endif; ?>


    <?php //Above Post Banner
    if(  empty( $get_meta["tie_hide_above"][0] ) ){
        if( !empty( $get_meta["tie_banner_above"][0] ) ) echo '<div class="e3lan e3lan-post">' .htmlspecialchars_decode($get_meta["tie_banner_above"][0]) .'</div>';
        else tie_banner('banner_above' , '<div class="e3lan e3lan-post">' , '</div>' );
    }
    ?>

    <article <?php post_class('post-listing'); ?> id="the-post">
        <?php if( empty( $get_meta["tie_post_head_cover"][0] ) ) get_template_part( 'framework/parts/post-head' ); ?>

        <div class="post-inner">

        <?php if(  empty( $get_meta["tie_post_head_cover"][0] ) || ( empty( $get_meta["tie_post_head"][0] ) &&  !tie_get_option( 'post_featured' ) ) ||
                ( !empty( $get_meta["tie_post_head_cover"][0] ) && ( !empty( $get_meta['tie_post_head'][0] ) && $get_meta['tie_post_head'][0] != 'thumb' ) ) ) : ?>
            <h1 class="name post-title entry-title" itemprop="itemReviewed" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Thing"><span itemprop="name"><?php the_title(); ?></span></h1>

            <?php get_template_part( 'framework/parts/meta-post' ); ?>
        <?php endif; ?>

            <div class="entry">
                <?php if( ( tie_get_option( 'share_post_top' ) &&  empty( $get_meta["tie_hide_share"][0] ) ) || ( !empty( $get_meta["tie_hide_share"][0] ) && $get_meta["tie_hide_share"][0] == 'no' ) ) get_template_part( 'framework/parts/share'  ); // Get Share Button template ?>

                <?php if( tie_get_option( 'related_position' ) == 'in' ) get_template_part( 'framework/parts/related-posts' ); ?>

                <?php the_content(); ?>
                <?php wp_link_pages( array( 'before' => '<div class="page-link">' . __ti( 'Pages:' ), 'after' => '</div>' ) ); ?>

                <?php edit_post_link( __ti( 'Edit' ), '<span class="edit-link">', '</span>' ); ?>
            </div><!-- .entry /-->
            <?php the_tags( '<span style="display:none">',' ', '</span>'); ?>
            <span style="display:none" class="updated"><?php the_time( 'Y-m-d' ); ?></span>
            <?php if ( get_the_author_meta( 'google' ) ){ ?>
            <div style="display:none" class="vcard author" itemprop="author" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Person"><strong class="fn" itemprop="name"><a href="<?php the_author_meta( 'google' ); ?>?rel=author">+<?php echo get_the_author(); ?></a></strong></div>
            <?php }else{ ?>
            <div style="display:none" class="vcard author" itemprop="author" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Person"><strong class="fn" itemprop="name"><?php the_author_posts_link(); ?></strong></div>
            <?php } ?>

            <?php if( ( tie_get_option( 'share_post' ) && empty( $get_meta["tie_hide_share"][0] ) ) || ( !empty( $get_meta["tie_hide_share"][0] ) && $get_meta["tie_hide_share"][0] == 'no' ) ) get_template_part( 'framework/parts/share' ); // Get Share Button template ?>
            <div class="clear"></div>
        </div><!-- .post-inner -->
    </article><!-- .post-listing -->
    <?php if( tie_get_option( 'post_tags' ) ) the_tags( '<p class="post-tag">'.__ti( 'Tags ' )  ,' ', '</p>'); ?>


    <?php //Below Post Banner
    if( empty( $get_meta["tie_hide_below"][0] ) ){
        if( !empty( $get_meta["tie_banner_below"][0] ) ) echo '<div class="e3lan e3lan-post">' .htmlspecialchars_decode($get_meta["tie_banner_below"][0]) .'</div>';
        else tie_banner('banner_below' , '<div class="e3lan e3lan-post">' , '</div>' );
    }
    ?>

    <?php if( ( tie_get_option( 'post_authorbio' ) && empty( $get_meta["tie_hide_author"][0] ) ) || ( isset( $get_meta["tie_hide_related"][0] ) && $get_meta["tie_hide_author"][0] == 'no' ) ): ?>      
    <section id="author-box">
        <div class="block-head">
            <h3><?php _eti( 'About' ) ?> <?php the_author() ?> </h3><div class="stripe-line"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="post-listing">
            <?php tie_author_box() ?>
        </div>
    </section><!-- #author-box -->
    <?php endif; ?>


    <?php if( tie_get_option( 'post_nav' ) ): ?>                
    <div class="post-navigation">
        <div class="post-previous"><?php previous_post_link( '%link', '<span>'. __ti( 'Previous' ).'</span> %title' ); ?></div>
        <div class="post-next"><?php next_post_link( '%link', '<span>'. __ti( 'Next' ).'</span> %title' ); ?></div>
    </div><!-- .post-navigation -->
    <?php endif; ?>

    <?php if( tie_get_option( 'related_position' ) != 'in' ) get_template_part( 'framework/parts/related-posts' ); ?>

    <?php get_template_part( 'framework/parts/check-also' ); ?>

    <?php endwhile;?>

    <?php comments_template( '', true ); ?>

</div><!-- .content -->
```

Answer (score 0):

This is quite tricky since we don't have access to the template parts like "post-head" and "meta-post" so not too sure what might break but make a backup copy of your single.php and then try this.

Change this piece of code

```
<article <?php post_class('post-listing'); ?> id="the-post">
    <?php if( empty( $get_meta["tie_post_head_cover"][0] ) ) get_template_part( 'framework/parts/post-head' ); ?>

    <div class="post-inner">

    <?php if(  empty( $get_meta["tie_post_head_cover"][0] ) || ( empty( $get_meta["tie_post_head"][0] ) &&  !tie_get_option( 'post_featured' ) ) ||
            ( !empty( $get_meta["tie_post_head_cover"][0] ) && ( !empty( $get_meta['tie_post_head'][0] ) && $get_meta['tie_post_head'][0] != 'thumb' ) ) ) : ?>
        <h1 class="name post-title entry-title" itemprop="itemReviewed" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Thing"><span itemprop="name"><?php the_title(); ?></span></h1>

        <?php get_template_part( 'framework/parts/meta-post' ); ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
```

to this

```
<article <?php post_class('post-listing'); ?> id="the-post">

        <?php if(  empty( $get_meta["tie_post_head_cover"][0] ) || ( empty( $get_meta["tie_post_head"][0] ) &&  !tie_get_option( 'post_featured' ) ) ||
            ( !empty( $get_meta["tie_post_head_cover"][0] ) && ( !empty( $get_meta['tie_post_head'][0] ) && $get_meta['tie_post_head'][0] != 'thumb' ) ) ) : ?>
        <h1 class="name post-title entry-title" itemprop="itemReviewed" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Thing"><span itemprop="name"><?php the_title(); ?></span></h1>

        <?php get_template_part( 'framework/parts/meta-post' ); ?>
    <?php endif; ?>

    <?php if( empty( $get_meta["tie_post_head_cover"][0] ) ) get_template_part( 'framework/parts/post-head' ); ?>

    <div class="post-inner">
```